# How to dynamically generate a link with query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hi fellow developers,

I want to integrate affiliate program for my website, to earn commissions from bookings made via my links.

Since, I have those properties on my site as well, I need a user to be able to click "book it" and get redirected to a page on booking.com with that particular place highlighted.

So the link has this params, which I need:

http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=-2900142&aid=814610&checkin_monthday=25&checkin_month=3&checkin_year=2017&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_month=3&checkout_year=2017&no_rooms=1&group_adults=1&highlighted_hotels=2197459

City = I have custom field for it,so wordpress can pick it with

```
get_post_meta(CityID)
```

Highlighted_hotels = makes this particular object highlighted if it's available, also I have it in custom field, so I can take it with

```
get_post_meta(HotelID)
```

But how do I take date values from dropdowns? And how do I make a link afterwards? with

```
<?php echo '<a href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?';
echo $city;
echo $highlighted;
echo $dates;
```

Is this a correct method to create a link on wordpress?

Btw, I'm using an official booking.com plugin right now, but it's broken and doesn't fill my needs, I want to change it with above custom code, but you can take a look at what I want to achieve on my site here for example (russian language) :
http://sochi.asp.sale/nedvizhimost/chvizhepse/posutochno/kompleks-zolotoj-kashtan/

Form is on the right side bottom.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to take the values from the dropdown like so:

```
var e = document.getElementById("DROPDOWN_NAME");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Now to build a URL just use the variable created called strUser.

```
var url = "http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?" + strUser;
```

I hope that is clear and helps.

EDIT:

If you want to use php to build the link, append the values to the url variable:

```
<?php echo '<a href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?' . $city . '&' . $highlighted . '&' . $dates;
```

That will echo the completed url with all the variables added onto the end of it.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this, when I'm back at the computer. 

I'm not very good with javascript, these lines you gave seem too complex for me to understand, can you add a comment next to them, what they do?
It's not really clear, how to add mutiple values with that e.options, i mean date, month, date, month.

Php looks really simple to implement, i don't need a comment on that.  
Will post back here, when I manage it.

Comment: The variable e will hold the values from the dropdown box then when a user selects a value from the box the selected value is stored in the variable strUser.

Comment: So I followed your php advice and made a simplified version without date picker, but still it works very well - 
You can see it's simple version, on this object for example: http://sochi.asp.sale/nedvizhimost/adler/posutochno/gostevoj-dom-svetlana/ 

Thanks!